# Android wallpaper also sliding left and right when we swipe the home screen

Tags: android-layout, android, homescreen

I want to develop a new home screen application for android. I saw the default home screen in my android 2.3.3 device, when ever I swipe the home screen left and right, the background wallpaper also sliding left and right. What is that view? How to get the same effect in an app?

Is it `ViewPager`? I checked the `ViewPager` class, but I didn't found any common background image for all views in that.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a canvas with a draw-able, then detect the users swiping and animate it in the background. It is likely that the default android backgrounds are doing the same. You wont be drawing the unseen portions of the view.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html

I suggest doing their lunar lander tutorial to learn how to use the canvas first.

You will make a canvas the background to your app and then lay your other ui elements on top of it unless you make the ui based inside the canvas.